# Maximize a function of $x$ and $y$ where $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

I have the following function:
$f(x,y) = x(y^2-x^2)- \frac{(x^2 +y^2)^2}{2\rho}+\frac{3x^2(y^2-4x^2)}{\rho}$ where $\rho>0$ is a constant.

My goal is to find the maximum value of this function subject to the constraint $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

My thoughts:

1. I  think I can replace the second term $\frac{(x^2 +y^2)^2}{2\rho}$ with $\frac{1}{2\rho}$ since due to the constraint $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$.

But, I am not sure how to proceed. Can someone show me the steps for solving this problem? What would be the easiest way to approach this?

Comment: I would compute the gradient and find the critical points in the interior of the domain (i.e. $x^2+y^2<1$). On the boundary you can use that $y^2=1-x^2$ to express the function only in terms of $x$ and compute the derivative of that for $-1<x<1$ and finally check the endpoints $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: Your assumption 1 works only for the boundary.  Steverin said there may be extrema in the interior points of $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.
What approaches have you been learning?
This one is one of the more popular approaches.
https://calcworkshop.com/partial-derivatives/extrema-multivariable-functions/

Comment: And this one incorporates constraints.
https://ximera.osu.edu/mklynn2/multivariable/content/04_7_lagrange_multipliers/lagrange_multipliers